# RegEx: Look-behind to avoid odd number of consecutive backslashes

Tags: php, regex, pcre, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

I have user input where some tags are allowed inside square brackets. I've already wrote the regex pattern to find and validate what's inside the brackets.

In user input field opening-bracket could ([) be escaped with backslash, also backslash could be escaped with another backslash (\). I need look-behind sub-pattern to avoid odd number of consecutive backslashes before opening-bracket.

At the moment I must deal with something like this:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\[(?<inside brackets>.*?)]
```

It works fine, but problem is that this code still matches possible pairs of consecutive backslashes in front of brackets (even they are hidden) and look-behind just checks out if there's another single backslash appended to pairs (or directly to opening-bracket). I need to avoid them all inside look-behind group if possible.

### Example:

```
my [test] string is ok
my \[test] string is wrong
my \\[test] string is ok
my \\\[test] string is wrong
my \\\\[test] string is ok
my \\\\\[test] string is wrong
...
etc
```

I work with PHP PCRE

Comment: Is there a finite limit to how many odd ones?  Would 1,3,5,and 7 be enough to avoid?  I assume you will let through 2,4,6,8 though?

Comment: @tchrist Unfortunately no, it's almost infinite. I found some examples in my database with 40+ consecutive slashes. Some guys are using them to make ASCII 'drawings' then use tags to color some elements or make hyperlinks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Last time I checked, PHP did not support variable-length lookbehinds. That is why you cannot use the trivial solution `(?<![^\\](?:\\\\)*\\)`.

The simplest workaround would be to simply match the entire thing, not just the brackets part:

```
(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\[(?<inside_brackets>.*?)]
```

The difference is that now, if you're using that regex in a `preg_replace`, you gotta remember to prefix the replacement string by `$1`, to restore the backslashes being there.

Comment: +1 I found in manual that there are some limitations inside look-behind sub-pattern so I guess you're right about variable-length. Matching entire string and pulling out just what's inside the brackets is not a problem. I'm doing that at the moment. Some REGEX flavors allow full-pattern in look behinds, such as .NET but I was wonderingis it possible in PCRE. Btw, i'm using that pattern in preg_match_all(). However, thanks for your answer.

Comment: No, it is not possible in PCRE; the whole-string-matching thing is simply a workaround for that. It provides the same functionality, at the cost of having to re-add those characters yourself, and excluding the extra matched region from the possible matches. This is not a problem here since the part of the string in question can only contain backslashes, so there cannot be a brackets match there.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: The regex you accepted `(?<![^\\])<etc...>` was incorrect. It was doing a *negative* lookbehind for a *negated* character class (containing a backslash), thereby making it a *positive* lookbehind for a backslash. You need to use `(?<!\\)` instead! I took the liberty to edit this answer.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - yes, I saw that earlier, but I accepted this answer because there's no solution for my problem in PCRE and opening sentence of this answer explains why.

Comment: @Tim, `(?<![^\\])` is not equivalent to `(?<=\\)`.  The former will match at the beginning of the string if there's a match to be had there, while the latter requires the presence of at least one intervening character (i.e., a backslash).  And yes, I know you're actually using `(?<!\\)` and not `(?<=\\)` (and correctly so, IMHO), but I couldn't let that remark go unchallenged. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without any look-behinds at all (*the `(\\\\|[^\\])` alternation eats anything but a single back-slash*):

```
^(\\\\|[^\\])*\[(?<brackets>.*?)\]
```

Comment: I need backslashes as part of look-behind group. I already have plenty of solutions w/out lookbehinds, there's one of them which works perfectly posted in question above. I don't need alternatives how to do same job in another way. Etienne Perot in his answer says that what I'm looking for is impossible with PCRE, so I have solution to believe he's wrong (which I highly doubt) or to rewrite entire project using .NET because so far .NET only uses REGEX flavor which supports full-pattern in look-behind.

Comment: btw, your example has two huge mistakes... 1. anchor ^ searches at the begining of the string only, 2. group (\\\\|[^\\]) requires at least one character before opening-bracket and that doesn't work if document starts with tag.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: Change the + to an * asterisk, and it works at the start of the string too.  Pretty obvious.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: And the answer posted above DOES have lookbehinds in it, what do you think this is: (?<!\\\\)    ?

Comment: Yes mate, it's one of reasons why I accepted that answer. Btw, pattern from that answer is exact copy of one I've originally posted in the question. Look this example `"This [is] my [test][string]"` and tell me does your pattern matches all tags - `is`, `this` and `string`? Also, my question says **"I need to avoid them all (backslashes) inside look-behind group if possible"** and your answer just doesn't do that. According to original question I expected answer like "Yes, that's possible followed w/ look-behind pattern" or "No, it's not possible". Simple as that.

Comment: My pattern would've matched the word "is" if run on that test string, which is what exactly what it tries to do - I can only read what you actually wrote down, not what's in your head.   And another thing:  my answer is not a critique of Etienne's answer in any way, nor a proposal that you should not use look-behinds, but merely to offer a different perspective.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8689/discussion-between-sweaver2112-and-wh1t3h4ck5)