# More Efficient Way to Find/Replace Non-Escaped Characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to find the best way to find and replace (in Ruby 1.9.2) all instances of a special code (%x) preceded by **zero, or an even number of backslashes**.

In other words, :

```
%x      -->   FOO
\%x     -->   \%x
\\%x    -->   \\FOO
\\\%x   -->   \\\%x
\\\\%x  -->   \\\\FOO
etc.
```

There may be multiple instances in a string:   "This is my %x string with two %x codes."

With help from the questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613522/regex-look-behind-to-avoid-odd-number-of-consecutive-backslashes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297907/regex-odd-number-of-occurences-of-a-char) I got the following code to do what I want:

```
 str.gsub(/
  (?<!\\)           # Not preceded by a single backslash
  ((?:\\\\)*)       # Eat up any sets of double backslashes - match group 1  
  (%x)              # Match the code itself - match group 2
  /x, 

  # Keep the double backslashes (match group 1) then put in the sub
  "\\1foo")
```

That regex seems kind of heavyweight, though.  Since this code will be called with reasonable frequency in my application, I want to make sure I'm not missing a better (cleaner/more efficient) way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine two alternative regular expressions:

1. Using a look-behind assertion, as in your code. (look-behind-2)
2. Matching one more character, before the back-slashes. (alternative)

Other than that, I do only see a minor optimization for your regular expression. The "%x" is constant, so you do not have to capture it. (look-behind-1)

I am not sure which of these is actually more efficient. Therefore, I created a small benchmark:

```
$ perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $test = '%x \%x \\%x \\\%x \\\\%x \\\\\%x \\\\%x \\\%x \\%x \%x %x';

cmpthese 1_000_000, {
    'look-behind-1' => sub { (my $t = $test) =~ s/(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\%x/${1}foo/g },
    'look-behind-2' => sub { (my $t = $test) =~ s/(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)(\%x)/${1}foo/g },
    'alternative'   => sub { (my $t = $test) =~ s/((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*)\%x/${1}foo/g },
};
```

Results:

```
                  Rate   alternative look-behind-2 look-behind-1
alternative   145349/s            --          -23%          -26%
look-behind-2 188324/s           30%            --           -5%
look-behind-1 197239/s           36%            5%            --
```

As you can clearly see, the alternative regular expression is far behind the look-behind approach and capturing the "%x" is slightly slower than not capturing it.

regards, Matthias